# Express serves static files that are not in root directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a website with a lot of HD videos so I want to put the videos files outside of web root directory.

Here is my web root directory:

```
/var/node/myapp
```

For some basic static files like **javascript**, **css**... I put them in public directory.

```
/var/node/myapp/public
```

For video files I want to put here

```
/hdd/videos
```

This is my current serve static code:

```
app.use(serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
    maxAge: keys.conf.maxAge,
    etag: true,
    setHeaders: setCustomCacheControl
  }));
  function setCustomCacheControl (res, path) {
    if (serveStatic.mime.lookup(path) === 'text/html') {
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=0')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set multiple static directories. Example:

```
app.use(express.static('public', {etag: true, maxAge: keys.conf.maxAge}));
app.use(express.static('/hdd/videos'));
```

*However, the path that you provide to the express.static function is relative to the directory from where you launch your node process. If you run the express app from another directory, it’s safer to use the absolute path of the directory that you want to serve.*

Document for express static file in [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: This fails to answer the asker's problem of pointing nodejs to a directory outside of the node process. In your example, the second line will route inside the node process directory to `/var/node/myapp/hdd/videos` instead of outside the root directory to `..somewhere outside root../hdd/videos`

Comment: You’re wrong! I said that “If you run the express app from another directory, it’s safer to use the absolute path of the directory that you want to serve.” I don’t know which is absolute path, just example :))

Comment: May be /root/home/hdd/videos or anything else. Don’t copy, paste then run without modify my code.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have a directory accessed outside of the root web server you'll need to go up a directory level via `..`. You didn't specify where exactly `/hdd/videos` is in relation to your root directory, but it should change to look something like this:

```
var videosDirectory = __dirname + '/../../hdd/videos';
app.use(serveStatic(videosDirectory, {
    maxAge: keys.conf.maxAge,
    etag: true,
    setHeaders: setCustomCacheControl
    }));
    function setCustomCacheControl (res, path) {
      if (serveStatic.mime.lookup(path) === 'text/html') {
      res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=0')
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to keep the public directory to serve css files. Please show me how

Comment: Then keep your existing public directory app.use() function, but before that function insert a app.use(`/videos`, express.static(videosDirectory)). Now you can make calls to /vidoes/birdvideo and it will internally route to /hdd/videos/birdvideo

Answer (score -1):

You can create a [symlink](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ln) under `/var/node/myapp/public` to point to `/hdd/videos`:

On Linux/Unix/OSX, for example:

```
ln -s /hdd/videos /var/node/myapp/public/videos
```

This way you don't expose your entire root directory, and you can separate where you store the actual videos from where you serve them without copying or moving them when they're added/removed/etc.

When the user hits your route `/videos` it will look for it under `/var/node/myapp/public` as per your static route. It will see `videos` as a link and follow that link to `/hdd/videos` where the videos will be available.